# Non-English question in LQ queue

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, english

In the LQ review queue I've stumbled upon a [non-English question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25939253/health-monitoring-aspnet-webauthenticationsuccessauditevent).

My resolution was to open the question in a new tab and flag for moderator attention. Was that the right decision?

Comment: "Unclear what you're asking" seems appropriate here.

Comment: @Servy's advice seems to apply well here. Though, if you're willing to do so, you could put the question to a translation (to english) engine and edit with the results. Or at least leave a comment for the OP to do so.

Comment: The main StackOverflow site is English language only. Therefore, all questions have to be in English. While the advice to possibly translate the question using a web engine might be nice, if the poster can't ask the question in English it's highly unlikely they'll be able to understand an answer in English either, and most translation engines don't do well with technical terms. The proper response here IMO is to vote to close as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: I've seem people use a custom Off Topic close reason for this case, saying something like "question is not in English". But "unclear what you're asking" sounds perfectly reasonable as well.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I can't really see where I can give a custom off topic close reason, I think that option was removed.

Comment: @Servy well a non-English question is really pretty unclear. I'll choose that next time, thanks.

Comment: @Csq custom close vote comments / reasons are only available for people with actual close votes rather than just flags.  IIRC for a period of time when custom close flags were available there were some very strange suggested close reasons that didn't jive with the rest of the close vote guidance.  Thus, only people who can cast close votes get to put in a custom topic - for the rest of the <3ks, it is now 'blatantly off topic' as the "this doesn't even..." reason rather than something they can write themselves.

Comment: @Csq Yes, I had forgotten that you can review in the LQ queue before casting close votes. Sorry if that caused any confusion. It actually doesn't make much sense to me that people can review LQ questions, but then not cast close votes. Because that's the only reasonable action if a question really *is* low quality. Flagging does not seem useful, since it's already in the review queue.

Answer (score 18):

Voting to close it as off-topic would've been just as good.

There's no explicit option for "Off topic because it's not written in English", but you could just select "other" and type "not english" and you'd be good to go.

Or if that all sounds like too much work, "Unclear" fits too. I mean, who *really* understands Spanish?

#### Related:

- [Migrate to Stack Overflow Portuguese](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275640/migrate-to-stack-overflow-portuguese)
- [Flag question that belongs to Portugees StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271774/flag-question-that-belongs-to-portugees-stackoverflow/)
- [Fluent in Spanish? We're hiring a Community Manager for a Spanish Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271998/fluent-in-spanish-were-hiring-a-community-manager-for-a-spanish-stack-overflow)

Answer (score -12):

If you prefer the non-destructive solutions (for example, you remember very well to the same cases in your beginner time as your perfectly good question was simply closed), then there is also an alternative.

If it isn't, then translate its content with the google translate, and then make a manual fixup by your English. If you have luck, grammar/spelling fixers will find the post before the VtC/VtD votes.

---

In theory, if the question is from an SE-supported language (Russian, Japanese, Spanish and Portuguese), then it could be eligible for a mod migration to these sites. Here the problem is that in this case, the mod migrating the question should take some responsibility about it, what can't be done without knowing the language of the target site.

Comment: As I can remember, I already saved some Chinese questions on this way.

Comment: I can only speak for myself, but I will *not* migrate questions that are written in a language that I cannot read. (Because if I can't read them, I can't tell if they're decent questions or not. We don't migrate our garbage to other sites.) So that leaves me only considering migrating question written in English and maybe other Germanic languages. **Translating the post to English is a better idea, if you want to salvage it.**

Comment: @CodyGray The FAQ explicitly [advises against translating posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/812149). (I do note that you called it "a better idea", and not "a good idea").

Comment: Right, it's not a great idea because the OP can't respond to feedback. But if you really think it's a good question that can stand on its own without the OP, then translating it *might* be appropriate.

Comment: Translation is not suitable; there's no guarantee that the OP will understand the language that it's translated to.  Migration is not suitable; you can't expect moderators to be fluent in the target language *and* be somewhat able to decipher if the question is on-topic.  Unfortunately, this advice is just not tenable.

Comment: @Makoto It is right, but maybe the mods or the reviewers of the target site should decide about this. *All* the migrations should be decided (or, maybe, even initiated) by the members of the target site.

Comment: @peterh:  We're the ones initiating the migration, and in all frankness, we should be confident that the question is good enough to warrant migration in the first place.  Without that confidence, [we're migrating crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113429/175248).

Comment: @Makoto I say, "X is bad, Y would be correct", and now you come to explain "X is being done". Thank you very much for your very "smart" comment, you made my day.