# Flag question that belongs to Portuguese Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, flags

I ran on to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948881/como-a%C3%B1adir-a-las-publicaciones-de-mi-blog-en-mi-perfil-de-google-un-bot%C3%B3n-inte) question. OP is clearly not aware of Portugal language spoken Stack Overflow site.

How should I flag the question to bring moderators' attention to move the question to other site?

Comment: You flag it as 'other', then explain.

Comment: Because the Portuguese Stack Overflow site is still in beta, it cannot yet be added to the target list, see [Migration of code questions from StackOverflow to CodeReview](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749)

Comment: However, you should do this for quality questions *only*. Google Translate makes a bit of a mess of translating that post, but it doesn't look like it'd be worthy of migrating at all and is likely to be closed on PT in any case.

Comment: That's Spanish, not Portugese (made the same mistake myself once).

Answer (score 6):

This is a special case that I don't believe is covered by the other question.

Frankly, we probably won't ever migrate questions to the Portuguese Stack Overflow site, *ever*. We, as moderators, do not know Portuguese and cannot vouch for the quality of the question to make that kind of decision. It doesn't make sense for us or *anyone else* in the community who is not familiar with Portuguese to send a question to that site. Translators are not always the most reliable tools and an "educated guess" is not an adequate reason to involve questions in the migration process.

If you know Portuguese and you think the question would be a suitable question on that site, then post a comment directing the user to that site and vote to close the question here.

Comment: Does that stand even if a trusted user from the portuguese site asks for the migration (let's make him a mod there, even...)?

Comment: Trusted user? Probably won't migrate. Moderator? Probably would, because they are basically vouching the question for us. Trusted users don't always understand the "don't migrate crap" rule and can sometimes cast some pretty bad migration flags.