# Fluent in Spanish? We're hiring a Community Manager for a Spanish Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, international-sites

Here's where you can find the [full details](https://hire.jobvite.com/j?cj=oNY1Yfwu&s=Stack_Meta) and [application](https://hire.jobvite.com/j?aj=oNY1Yfwu&s=Stack_Meta).  But if you hate clicking:

#### Requirements

If you're fluent in Spanish and you're reading this, you likely have at least 75% of the things we're looking for for this role:

1. Fluency in English and Spanish (native-level *writing* in Spanish)
2. Enough programming experience or training to be the only moderator / company liaison to the community on a Spanish-language Stack Overflow (at least at first)
3. Experience using Stack Exchange sites (huge rep is *not* required, but we want someone who gets and loves the system.)
4. Comfort owning and overseeing a multi-step plan. International site rollouts involve a fair bit of planning, and each one is different.  You'd be responsible (with help from a senior CM) for establishing and overseeing execution of a rollout plan.

#### What we *generally* look for in Community Manager candidates:

- **Very strong writing skills** - you'll need to articulate complex ideas in clear, compelling ways. In the beginning, you will be the sole guiding voice of the company.  The community will help decide what it's going to be, but you'll need to help articulate what they should consider, initial guidelines, etc.
- **Moderation / conflict resolution** - despite our best efforts, not everyone on the internet always agrees. Part of the job is helping to recognize how to handle conflicts in ways that may not have a winner, but let *both* parties get back to doing what they came for - helping increase programming knowledge.
- **Understanding of community dynamics** and what motivates people to donate their time on sites like ours
- **Extremely self-motivated with strong ability to prioritize**.  We ask CMs to help figure out what to do, not just to do it. And [many of us work remotely](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/02/why-we-still-believe-in-working-remotely/).

Note that the role is not going to be limited to covering a future Spanish-language site.  We're hiring someone who will function like our current CMs do now, but will be able to be the primary Spanish language rep for the Community Team when we are ready to roll out Spanish site(s) in the future.

#### How many of these are you planning to roll out, anyway?

[This post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/) lays out *why* we're launching non-English sites. We're *extremely* pleased with the success of [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) - it's serving a community that mostly wasn't able to be as active on SO.  But we greatly value *centralized* knowledge, so we're not looking to hit every language - many seem well served on SO, and being all together *when possible* is better for everyone.

In the interest of full transparency, here are the only languages we're committed to:

- Portuguese (live)
- Japanese (in progress)
- Spanish
- Russian

There are probably another 4-6 that clearly merit consideration, but we're going to limit our current outlook to these four, and see what we learn.

Since I wrote too many words, and may have made you scroll the action links off the page:

**Here's where you can find the [full details](https://hire.jobvite.com/j?cj=oNY1Yfwu&s=Stack_Meta) and [application](https://hire.jobvite.com/j?aj=oNY1Yfwu&s=Stack_Meta).**

> #### Editorial note:
>
> I'm purging the comments here, because once again they've gotten *super-noisy* and I'm concerned some of them are discouraging folks from posting *answers*. Fortunately, most of the more insightful comments have *already* been superseded by answers, but for the sake of future readers here are some quick notes:
>
> - **This post is on meta because we want to be open to feedback.** That's why there's a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag below it. Feel free to discuss any part of it - just be polite, and try to do your research first. In particular, if you have questions/concerns about the job, raise them in an answer. Yes, questions on meta are a bit different - [that's by-design](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).
> - **This post is on *this* meta because a significant chunk of the folks who want this site are already on SO,** and want a place where they can bring even more people into the fold.
> - **Yes, it's a full-time job**, and you can work from wherever you want as long as it has internet access.
> - **No, I'm not worried about posts like this destroying the purity of meta.** [Meta is a chimera, a terrifying abomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238990/should-stack-exchange-inc-promote-its-pet-projects-on-meta-sites/239096#239096) - you gotta just make the most of it.
>
> -Shog9

Comment: A bit off-topic, but why was Portuguese the first language chosen for localization? And now Spanish (a very similar language) is second? Did you see metrics that suggested Portuguese was the 2nd most used language after English by SO users? Or did you just draw from a hat, and the choice could have easily been Spanish first, or Mandarin, or Russian, or German, or Italian, or French, or British English (hue hue)? I am just curious.

Comment: @TylerH, we were mostly looking at the languages that had the most total devs who we thought might NOT be willing/able to participate in English, but might be excited to in their native language. Within that list, we wanted to start with language that uses the same alphabet, to make initial localization easier.  That made Portuguese a good fit.

Comment: This may be a bit late but shouldn't "*written skills*" be "*writing skills*"?

Comment: @renan, I never said *I* met the requirements. Sigh.

Comment: @Jaydles Is there any more information available about the Japanese site? I don't see anything on Area 51 and I'm curious about it. It would be nice to be able to follow the progress.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, good timing.  Jmac, the CM "Warden of the East" was just talking to the team about the best place to share progress on getting the site ready.  I think he'll probably create a discussion on A51 for now.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot As Jaydles said, I'm looking in to how to do stuff without breaking stuff and still letting you know. I will ping you with details once I get it set up.

Comment: How about Chinese? Is that a possibility?

Comment: @AveMaleficum, yes, they're squarely in the "next few" category. Which is to say *if* we expand to a few more after the four we've committed to, China will very likely be one of them.

Comment: Working remotely from outside the US is allowed from what I understand, but what happens if the candidate happens to live in a country where he/she requires a visa to stay and a work permit to legally perform a job (Even if the job is done remotely for a US based company)? I don't think SO has any company setup in Thailand so that, unfortunately, leaves me out :-(

Comment: @momo, I don't know the specifics of Thai law, but in many countries, long-term, consulting arrangements are an option.

Answer (score 115):

I'm one of these buggers that speak weird, foreign languages that only a minority can understand. I, too, was initially against having multiple Stack Overflows (Stacks Overflow? Stack Overflow's?).

So SO *em Português*, as we call the Portuguese version (let's call it SOpt), was born. It happens to be my native language (I'm from *huehue*, as we call Brazil in some places). I decided to give it a chance. After some time, what initially seemed like a bad idea turned out to be a good one.

I noticed a few patterns there:

- When someone asks a good question that has not been asked in English before, the question gets asked in English in the original Stack Overflow (SO) too;
- When someone asks a question that has already had a good answer in SO, the most active users will link to the question in SO, along with translations of the most relevant parts of the best answers, as well as the translators' own comments.
- When someone asks something that has already been asked in SO, but has not had a good answer there, the question ends up getting good answers in both sites.

This leads to bilingual users, me included, visiting SO more and more, for references and updates on good answers.

IMO the effect of having multiple SO's for each language will not decentralize SO, nor get bilingual users away from it. Experience has shown that the opposite will happen :)

I do speak Spanish too, but this announcement has made me want to learn Japanese and Russian as well. Buena suerte, hermanos del Español! Ganbatee-yo, minna-san! Удачи, товарищи!

SOpt has also forced me to think about programming problems in more (human) languages. I'm not saying that any language is better than any other for programming... but being able to express your problems in multiple languages does add more points of view to the solution process, which ends up being very helpful.

Comment: **This is early and anecdotal, but it's exactly what we were hoping for.** I'll be honest - we weren't 100% sure what would happen with these.  We thought that the balkanization harm would be low, since anyone comfortable on SO(Eng) would probably tend to stay where the best answers are today, and we'd bring in *new* contributors.  But we were a little scared too.

Comment: I think it's great to see an answer from the perspective of a user who disliked, then used and enjoyed, SOpt. I think this answer gives excellent insight into how SOpt works, and how we can hope that this new Spanish SO will work.

Comment: This mirrors what I've heard from Gabe and others active on PT.SO. I gotta confess, I was pretty skeptical of this idea at the outset - but the proof of the pudding is in the eating, and the Portuguese community has devoured this opportunity *with gusto*. The essential goal of Stack Overflow has always been *communication* - not just with these machines, but with our peers... Improving the ability of programmers *everywhere* to communicate, creating bridges between formerly-isolated groups, is very much in keeping with this.

Comment: Would be nice to see some examples of this... it happens but can it be shown so? With links to both sites?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau search for "soen" in http://pt.stackoverflow.com and you'll see basically every case where SO has been referenced. My favorite ones are the most extensive discussions, such as [this](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8047/1658) and [this](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30638/1658). *"Fonte"* means source, so you have the links from SOpt to SO right there.

Comment: Referenced yes but answer that were on SOpt that were translated in English on SO... cause translating from SO to SOpt will be fairly common I suspect.

Comment: I can't remember any specific one right now but I'll do some digging and cite them here.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I have an example, sort of... About two years ago I asked [this question at SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12190338/520779) and got no useful answer. I asked [the same question at SOpt](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/889/215) and - while I ended up answering myself - the feedback I got from the other users (in special bfavaretto) was key to enable me to do this. Although I had forgotten about the original question, some time later an user with the same problem put a bounty in my question, prompting me to translate my answer back from SOpt to SOen.

Comment: I'm glad to see that but my concern is how often it will happen. Without some elbow grease from users, or a way to hint that a question/answer in some language could help in another language, we're not helping much more than before.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Sure, I was just giving an example (I was under the impression you were asking for one, but I might have misunderstood your comment) not trying to prove a point. In fact, if information is scarce in language A and plenty in language B the flow will more often than not be from B to A...

Comment: No, I was asking for examples since that proves it does happen, both ways. You also showed one way that process might happen (bounty on one side). I'm concerned about people, of all sites, missing good answers and knowledge cause it won't be translated for those needing it as there's no way, at the moment other than ourselves, to share the needed informations.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Yes, you will miss answers from people that can't write in English. Even if you put a gun in the mouth of these people you won't get answers from them. You will miss answers from people that doesn't use SO. Period.

Comment: @bigown Sort of. SO is missing my answers, because I chose to focus on SOpt. But how bad is that for SO? I'd like to think I'm so important that I'm being missed there, but that's probably not the case. There are lots of other people, many more skilled than me, answering questions in the same tags I did. So, is SO going to miss some users? I'd say yes. Will that ruin SO? Definitely not.

Comment: @bigown Those people were, are, missing out answers on SOen cause they can't be bothered to learn English and we now are easing that burden for them with SOpt and the other coming. Why would people on SOen be given the same treatment if a great answer resides on SOpt and is never translated? Life isn't fair but if you are supporting SOxx, you own to yourself to support a way to share the informations both ways, not only one way.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Yes, life isn't fair. And everyone knows best what is good for them.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau "can't be bothered to learn English"? Many can't even learn Portuguese properly because of our failed education system in Brazil. By sharing programming knowledge in Portuguese we're enabling more people to learn *programming*. English will come later, hopefully.

Comment: I've missed the count of how much people said things about "It's a great site, but I don't speak english, so I can't enjoy this knowledge".

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I might be misreading your comments again (did I mention I'm not a native en speaker? :P), but what makes english speakers **entitled** to the knowledge provided by non-speakers? Nobody has the obligation to translate anything from SOpt to SOen, as much as the reverse is true. If I decided to share some of my knowledge, and did so in a format that's not accessible to *you*, it's not my problem! I'm a volunteer here, I contribute as much as I want the way that I want, period. P.S. the comment I might have misread is "Why would people on SOen be given the same treatment if..."

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau As you can see in the [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i7mEN.png) SOpt is a success. I'm an active element in SOpt while in SOen I was merely a "search boy". SOen 1 year, 10 months 154 rep; SOpt 5 months 1,781 rep;
The SOpt community comes here to defending the OS in other languages ​​because it is a success and helps many people. Many of our responses are based on SOen... so SOen never die ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Reputation is a bad metric to show participation. I got 2k here but since I reached it, I've been doing a lot more reviewing than answering.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Never said once anyone is entitled to anything. I'm saying that we're helping the transfer of knowledge one way and not the other.

Comment: @bfavaretto I said "bothered" as there's a million reasons someone might not have learned English, it's just too long to enumerate them all.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Sorry for misinterpreting you then. In any case, as I said before, the transfer `en -> pt, es` is likely because information is plenty in the former and scarce in the latter. If it were the opposite, it would flow the other way. In any case, I see this flow as "natural", not "artificial" - by creating SOen first, and letting it aggregate a lot of knowledge, when SOpt came along it's natural that the bilingual speakers bring stuff from en to pt. When SOes comes out, the flow will be **both** from en -> es and pt -> es - since there are many people who speak those two but not en

Comment: Me agrada mucho la idea de tener un StackOverflow en Español, mucha gente en Latinoamerica se pierde la oprotunidad de aprender mucho mas por las barreras del lenguaje/ I'm really glad with the idea tath a Spanish Stack Overflow its in the oven, a lot of people in LatinAmerica its losing the oportunity to learn beacause the language barrier. Kudos!

Comment: Greeting from another HUE HUE BR!

Comment: I think the software should emphasize these beneficial patterns. I'd love to see the foreign-language posts in the "linked questions" list, just like Wikipedia has a "in other languages" box in the sidebar.

Comment: I strongly concur with the view that thinking about programming in more than one natural language can broaden one's perspective.  I think it's even more true of databases.

Answer (score 67):

I'm from Spain [that country of Europe where spanish language were founded :) ]

Well. I have a terrible english level. I know... But I know that too:

- English it's the main technical language for programmers and software engineers.
- The secret of steel it's the centralized knowledge. This is the power of SO. All of we search here.

My code it's on english. My doubts too.

So I not agree with this. I will use the original SO.

But it's only my opinion.

Comment: That is the spirit. This is not completely correct English, but we understand it, and appreciate the answer. That is all we need here to get the ball rolling.

Comment: `Spain [that country of Europe where spanish language were founded]`  ಠ_ಠ

Comment: dolan +1 It was a joke... It wouldn't be the first time that someone thinks that Spain it's near Brasil...

Comment: IMHO, that's exactly why localized SO won't work : people will look for answers where they  might actually find them, that is on english SO. And they'll ask their questions there too. Localized SO will most likely end up bloated with mediocre answers to mediocre questions because of that (and to be clear, not because non english speakers are mediocre, don't kill me right now :)

Comment: @X.L.Ant You don't have to speculate how it will end up. We've already done the experiment with SOpt and it is certainly not "bloated with mediocre answers to mediocre questions". I can't see why Spanish would be fundamentally different.

Comment: I agree. They have created "estouro da pilha" that is stack overflow version in portuguese. Portuguese is my natural language. I never used and will never use the portuguese version. First because 1)the top knowledge is on the english version because of the variety of people from different languages  2)who thinks to work with computers seriously nowadays have to talk english or have to find another job.

Comment: @X.L.Ant In SOpt we have some great answers that aren't present in the main site, besides local technical questions. Many users are finding better answers in their own language. There were cases where the OP posted the same question on SO and SOpt and got better and more numerous answers on SOpt. Sorry, but even though there are some concentration of great programmers here, you're just missing  other great programmers out there.

Comment: @utluiz And there it is, the decentralization of knowledge. Those better answers might never be translated to English, or other languages based SO sites. That's the real bad part of it.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I don't see a problem with that. Please check the utluiz reputation in SOPT and in SOEN (20k vs 264). What a great knowledge was not being shared with the community just of because of language and cultural barriers? Now in SOPT he is comfortable to participate and is being useful for several other people. Here, he was almost unnoticed, in all this 2 years of "participation". Same happened to several other persons.

Comment: @Math And the circle starts, the answer someone not fluent in any other language than English is in another language, he can't benefit from that answer unless he tries to translate it or learn the other language... We're not gaining more knowledge, we're spreading it unevenly. I'm not saying the other sites don't have a purpose, I'm saying we're not reaching the greatest number of people as SO should.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau that's right, we are spreading the knowledge, and I believe that is the point. How does having localized SO's is "not reaching the greatest number of people as SO should"? How would that be achievable by not having them? I can't get that..

Comment: @Math The only way right now for this to happen is that people that are fluent with many languages translate the questions/answers to share them but that will probably not happen to reach the greatest number.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau The "decentralization" of knowledge is a fallacy. It already is decentralized. Further, SO is not just a knowledge database. It helps real people to solve real problems. Yes, localized versions helps a lot. And the "barriers" that someone said is being raised is another fallacy, since when people come to know know SOxx and they like it, they will inevitably come to know other sites from SE. Yes, there are questions that will never take their way to SO, but the chances are they would never do anyway.

Comment: @utluiz Well I disagree that they wouldn't make it to SO. If someone is asking it somewhere, in whatever language, I bet you a million someone else, in another language, would also like an answer to that question.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau If millions would like to see the answer for such question, soon or later it will be asked here.

Comment: @utluiz The million is the bet I'm making, not the number of people wanting the answer. Even if a sole person in another language would like that answer, we're not, at the moment, doing a lot to get the knowledge across multiple languages.

Comment: Hi spanish person. I'm from one of those countries from the new world that speak spanish thanks to Spain. So... where is our gold!? ;) just kidding... I'm a fan of DRY so I didn't like the idea at glance. However, after some deep meditation, I think that SO in spanish is a great idea, because I know many programmers that don't use SO because they can't understand english, so this is a great opportunity for their professional growth and enrichment.

Comment: I live in Venezuela that country conquered by Spain where the Spanish language was perfected (teehehe) i have some known associates, college mates, among others who are amazing developers, with great logic and good skills, but they don't speak english very well, the logic of the code in english is one thing, but having to explain yourself in a proper grammar for the current language is not so easy.

Comment: I wanted to say this: there are many spanish forums. But I think that SO may be unique. I don't want to see how SO transforms in something like 'wikipedia', do you undestand me? But I respect the points of view that you're defending.

Comment: @DannyG Well, it was a bad joke (about how many english speakers use to see us) 
(Espero no haber ofendido a nadie eh? Nada más lejos de mi intención)

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez  The gold? I suppose that our politics spent it on market, to get more wood and stone, to reach the Imperial Age ... I used to do that on AoE

Comment: @CapitanCavernícola jajaja, yo hacía lo mismo para poder construir una gran muralla alrededor de mi ciudad. Pero nunca pude ganar en nivel difícil.

Comment: @CapitanCavernícola it ain't problem i was just following the joke in a weird-way :)

Comment: I'm from Peru [that country in South America that Spain invaded lot of years ago and made us learn and speak Spanish] and my native language is: yes, Spanish. And I learned English thanks to StackOverflow as well, but at least the place where I work at only 10 people of at least 50 programmers don't speak English and they have problems when using SOen. This also happens in lot of places in my country and I would dare to say this is extended in South America as well. I find this SOes initiative very interesting and promising, not for me but for these people that have problems with English.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza But, don't forget the Inca Empire (Italia invaded Spain? or Rome Republic invaded Iberian Peninsula?). 
Para qué habré puesto la gracia esa ... Lo decía por bromas como esta: [http://www.boredpanda.com/mapping-stereotypes/]

Comment: Did you mean "my questions too"?

Answer (score 66):

I'm just amazed to see that so many users of the SO site are so intolerant about this proposal

**What are you afraid of? In what way does the Spanish SO site affect you?**

Everyone can understand a bit of code and syntax in English, but it's not the same thing as having to explain yourself to a community of native and non-native English spoken users.

It is not like the SO main site is going to lose users, I am a native Spanish user and I will remain on SO, but if I have the chance to go to SPSO, to help other users who struggle with the proper English, while their questions get flagged, downvoted and rejected just because they can't speak the language properly?

I totally support this initiative.

Comment: standing ovation

Comment: Our concern is, primarily, about the splitting up of quality information, making it difficult to find. Remember that the primary goal of Stack Overflow at its inception was to create a single, authoritative, peer-reviewed resource containing answers to all sorts of common programming problems. If the answers are split across multiple language versions of the site, we've defeated our ability to reach this goal.

Comment: Furthermore, bilingual experts (e.g., people who speak both English and Spanish, but are native Spanish speakers) might move their participation entirely to the Spanish version of the site, robbing everyone else entirely of their knowledge. If they'd been forced to share it on the main (English) site, it would reach a broader audience.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree that there probably will be some transfer of knowledge, but I still disagree with the way this is written. "**Robbing**" everyone else (meaning that the knowledge belong to the english speaking userbase), "been **forced**" to share it on the main site

Comment: The knowledge *would* have been on the English site, had this spin-off not been created.

Comment: It's true, that's a real possibility, @Cody. But there are two reasons why I think it'll be less of a problem than some folks fear: first, if you *are* able to communicate effectively in both languages, having two sites *and* unique knowledge gives you the opportunity to share that knowledge with two separate communities - twice the benefit, twice the status. And second... I've watched what happened when we spun off Programmers and DBAs: some of the folks who were struggling or mostly lurking on SO *learned to do better* on the new sites and became *better* SO members as a result.

Comment: @CodyGray i guess you know nothing about the spanish community of developers, there are plenty other sites or forums where users can get the knowledge base completely on Spanish but those sites are not SO, and developers know that, Spanish site isn't gonna make me move completely from main site, that's silly, it's just gonna make me more active on StackExchange itself, I'm already active in around 7 more of the network sites, and that doesn't affect an user developement here

Comment: It certainly would affect my participation, @DannyG. I haven't the time to be an active, contributing member to a large number of Stack Exchange sites. I can barely manage one or two. If you can find the time in the day to do this, well, I'm both shocked and impressed. And no, I don't know anything about the Spanish community of developers, but having "plenty other sites or forums where users can get the knowledge" doesn't sound unique. We have the same thing in English, of course. Stack Overflow isn't the only, just the best. Having the information all together is a big part of why.

Comment: @Shog9 Yeah, I'm still trying to learn to love duplication. Your second reason is quite interesting, though. It would be nice to see some hard data on that. Maybe hard to do without singling out individuals, I don't know.

Comment: Should be possible (if somewhat difficult) using SEDE; I'll try to find the time to put something together.

Comment: Ugh, the "how does it affect you" argument. It's total nonsense. Murdering 20,000 people on the other side of the world doesn't have to "affect me personally" in order for me to find flaws in its execution.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Are you seriously comparing slaughter with a discussion about another language site? what is wrong with you?

Comment: @DannyG: Er, no? I'm critiquing this form of counter-argument.

Answer (score 47):

Having localized versions of SO, IMO is highly desirable.

Several extremely highly ranked users on SOPT today were contributing users on SO, but at *much* lower levels, for a really long time.  Meanwhile, once they felt like part of a community where they could give more, they became excellent contributors, and were able to share knowledge that they might never have been able to share without the creation of SOPT.

Here are some examples:

---

[utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/227/utluiz)
264 rep on SO in 2 years.
20.4K rep on SOPT in 9 months.

---

[bigown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/bigown)
612 rep on SO in 4 years and 9 months.
16.7K rep on SOPT in 9 months.

---

[Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco)
127 rep on SO in 3 years.
14.9K on SOPT in 9 months.

---

[Cigano Morrison Mendez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2999/cigano-morrison-mendez)
744 rep on SO in 2 years and 5 months.
14.3K rep on SOPT in 7 months.

---

<sup>These are just few, sorry, I can't list all of them.</sup>

I'm pretty sure that there are several others that fit in this pattern, but that are from different countries, and they will benefit from the localized SO's as well as the Lusophone community does.

Speaking for myself, I've never been a participative member in SO. I can't say exactly why, but I just didn't feel comfortable, I don't know.

Despite that, I am a dedicated member, as evidenced by the "Fanatic" badge I earned in Jul 9' 13 (by that time I had 163 rep), and my counter of visited days, which is currently at 559 days visited in just 1 year and 8 months (aprox. 92% of the days). But I've never really felt part of it, thus my relatively small contribution to the site. (This is my first post on Meta!)

Regarding the CM in SOES. I can't, sorry. I don't fulfill the roles.

<sup><sup>PS: Sorry for my bad English.</sup></sup>

Comment: I understand peoples chose AREA 51 to create several distinct sites. But why doing in a such way *(doing this by spliting)*? Why splitting reps since this is definitely the same target? I understand the reason for sites that  target language learning, but Stack Overflow is about technology : language isn't linked to the target at all. Why not doing a per question basis? Or a system where mods tell about the language they don't want to bother with while reviewing? ***Definitely : I don't understand why not sharing some structures between languages.***

Comment: Because it'd be *super-confusing*, @user2284570. Believe me, we discussed all of those ideas before settling on separate sites - after all, how awesome wouldn't it be to visit any question on SO and choose your language from the header? Problem is, this ignores the *people* who write these questions and answers. There are already "versions" of SO in other languages, sites that scrape the content and translate it somehow - but they're dead. No updates, no clarifications, no way for someone to ask a *new* question or have any idea if there's anyone with real expertise behind the facade...

Answer (score 35):

Sorry if this is not the right place to say this, but I really need to comment on something that has been bugging me for a while, ever since these "StackOverflow in language X" proposals appeared:

**Claim:**

> It's not good to fragment our community. Let's keep everything in English, so it will benefit the largest possible number of people.

Not only this assertion is false, but more importantly it's misguided!

- It's false because the proposal is not targeting people that are already in the community. It's targetting people that are **outside** the community.

  If I don't speak, say, Japanese, and there's a real cool blog post about something I'm interested in, this post has *zero* value to me. It's data, but it's not information. Actually it's worse than zero, it's *noise*. I'd better just ignore it, and thankfully Google does a pretty good job in hiding this stuff from me.

  If I spoke both Portuguese and Japanese, OTOH, I could compare that post with the stuff written in Portuguese, see which one has better info, and decide whether or not to join the Japanese community or stick to my own. Whatever I choose, I'll end up hurting one or another - at best I'll contribute *half* to each one even though I could commit fully to it (at the expense of the other one).

  If StackOverflow is launched in other languages, will existing contributors leave? Maybe. I can't speak for myself, since [I stopped contributing frequently to SOen long before SOpt came along](https://stackexchange.com/users/246559/mgibsonbr?tab=reputation). And while I don't know many other users, I noticed that [most of the top-ranked Brazilian users in SOen](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/78218/users-reputation-in-latin-america) chose to stick with the English site. *Some* loss is expected, of course, but forgive me to ask: how much will it matter?

  StackOverflow is **crowded**! Really! The reason I dediced to leave SOen as previously mentioned was because I was not having "fun" at it. There are just too many questions, and too many users elbowing each other to anwser them first. Add it to the fact that I take more time "parsing" English, thinking in Portuguese and finally "emitting" more English, and it was hard to me to be an useful, fast contributor. Even after years of practice, I'm just that much more productive while working with my native tongue than with a foreign one. I discovered with SOpt that I *like* working in Portuguese.

  So IMHO a small "brain drain" won't harm StackOverflow too much, if anything at all. Not counting the flock of n00bs that won't have anymore to write poorly written questions at SOen, having SOpt as a good alternative. It's not much either (there are many bad writers in the world, different language or not), but I'm betting the overall quality of SO will **improve**...
- What about "misguided"? Now, here's what really makes me angry at all this resistance against language specific sites: what is more important, to benefit the largest number of people or the people who **needs it the most?**

  I understand that StackExchange it not a non-profit, charitable organization, and that it will do what makes more business sense, hopefully within the boundary of ethics. But once someone start talking about "ideals", "spreding the knowledge", etc one has to realize that the people who need this knowledge the most are the ones who can not afford to learn English right away. Those who can already have a *huge* advantage over those who can't, even though there's always room for improvement of course.

  I can't tell how the software world will be 2000 years from now, not any more than someone 2000 years ago could predict that the whole world would not be speaking Latin today. But I acknowledge that in the current historical context any developer worth his salt will eventually have to learn English. Emphasis on "eventually". Requiring a foreign language as a pre-requirement to work in some industry raises the bar too much, it's a decision no sane community would impose on itself. Those communities of non-native English speakers will continue to develop software whether they have access to good resources in their native language or not.

  By denying these people access to a knowledge that would greatly improve their lives, and more often than not without creating a "competitor" to yourself (most software is developed in-house, and most businesses never leave their home country), on the basis that it will "diminish the knowledge available to me", that is... c'mon!... I shouldn't even have to explain this...

  For that reason, not only I applaud StackExchange for going through this route [of creating more localized SOs], but I'm not bothered at all the the "ideal of a centralized repository of knowledge" was weakened - since in doing so it enabled a higher ideal, of **knowledge to everyone**.

Now hoping that my little rant that took *so long* to write (aff, it's even harder to write prose in English than code) is not deleted as "does not answer the question"... :P

Comment: How about a "centralized repository of knowledge for everyone"?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau it's not for everyone if you don't reach out to everyone.

Comment: @Renan Exactly what I've been saying all along.

Comment: but then, once you reach everyone it's not very centralized anymore

Answer (score 26):

In short, I support any spin-off of SO in widely spoken languages. I just can't understand the outrageous reaction on having a Spanish version of SO.

Having clones of SO in other languages will surely serve more audience and doesn't aim to migrate talents from English SO to other clones. Not to mention that SE is a *profit company* and have the right to expand and discover new markets.

I am not going to speak on behalf of any SO user. My intention is to assist those who are seeking help in spite of their language, religion, nationality, etc. If you have other intentions, you may need to interview each and every *help-seeker* before offering your help.

Comment: "doesn't aim to migrate talents from English SO to other clones" Of course it will. But more importantly, it will most likely result in good information not getting back to SO, where they could benefit the largest number of people.

Comment: One language  spoken = more active community = skilled people = Good question =Good Answer

Comment: @K.B Well, yeah, unless you don't speak the one language, in which case, whoops, you'll just be turned away.  Do you really think there is, and can be, no other Web site on the Internet that will let people talk about programming in Spanish, one of the most widely spoken languages in the world?

Comment: The goal for the localization effort is to provide the site in languages where a _significant_ number of native speakers of that language do not fluently converse in English, and are unlikely to be motivated to do so. We've _always_ been about giving vibrant communities that are passionate about getting better at something a place to do it. For people that _only_ speak Spanish, Stack Overflow is _not_ that place. It's a site they can _perhaps_ manage to read, not a place where they can _participate_ and say _look what we built_. What's so wrong with giving that to them?

Comment: @emodendroket the all point is: regarding *programming* topic, you should at least be able to *read* English. In which case, you are not turned away. No need to duplicate/isolate technical information across multiple sites in multiple languages.

Comment: @TimPost The goal of the ones saying that it is a terrible idea is to provide SO with the largest number of experts as possible. What's wrong is that if they benefit from good info, I want to benefit from it too. When you have one place to manage, that is easy to do.

Comment: @VonC Maybe you "should" but it's demonstrably false that every professional programmer in the world is comfortable with English (and there's no rule that says you have to be a professional to post which makes this even more senseless).

Comment: @emodendroket I don't expect a programmer (professional or not) to be comfortable enough with English to post in SO. I do expect to find in *one* place the accurate and curated information that this programmer is looking for. That way, other (speaking different languages) will benefit from that same information.

Comment: @VonC Any talent has joined SO voluntary and can leave SO/SE without prior notice. If a talent finds its' _comfort zone_ outside SO, nobody can stop it.

Comment: @emodendroket Of course, but on the other hand, I tend to agree with VonC that not at least being able to read some english is a big flaw in programming, where most advanced documentation exist only in english.

Comment: @X.L.Ant Well, SO is hardly limited to only advanced programmers, and even if it were, we're contributing to the very deficit you're describing.

Comment: `outrageous reaction` for different opinion. Interesting living entity the humanity is.

Comment: @VonC By asking what the ramifications of bringing up a Spanish SO site would be for SO in terms of contributions SO would _not_ receive, you're asking me to document a negative, which is impossible. What I can say is, the people we're looking to serve are _not posting things on Stack Overflow_, so we're starting _from_ a total loss. I think what I haven't explained well is that my perspective is in fact the opposite.

Comment: @Lamak I have removed my previous comment about resenting potential SO users contributing instead on other SO instances, as the other answers in this page (and other comments like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271998/fluent-in-spanish-were-hiring-a-community-manager-for-a-spanish-stack-overflow#comment98383_272106) seem to prove my assertion is simply wrong.

Comment: @VonC I also removed my comment now.

Comment: *"Having clones of SO in other languages"* - the problem is they will NOT be CLONES.... they will be completely separate pages which only the spanish speaking people will benefit from...

Comment: @vba4all where's the problem if Spanish speakers benefit from it? Non-English speakers are not benefiting from SO-en, right? Either way, who seeks knowledge eagerly, will break all barriers to reach out for knowledge.

Comment: Did you mean "outraged reaction"?

Comment: @WalterMitty well, I meant ["first result".](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20outrageous%20reaction) ;)

Answer (score 19):

I have a couple of questions about this (I know, what crazy things am I doing here by not posting a rant about this, right?).

- The application description says "NYC or remote". How "remote" can it be?, can the position be fulfilled from a country outside the US?
- Would it be a full time job?, or can it be a side job?
- Is there only one position available?

Comment: We have employees all around the world. "Remote" can be anywhere with a good internet connection. It's full-time, and yes, there's only one position for a Spanish-speaking community manager.

Comment: Se olvidó de preguntar sobre las monedas ;)

Comment: @Laura Thanks for the answers. What's the time frame to receive applications?, and any idea of when should the spanish SO be launched?

Comment: @ypercube queras decir "medio de pago" ;)

Comment: As soon as possible, @Lamak - the job will be up until it is filled, and although we're not *quite* ready to set up the site yet the hazing process for new hires can take *months*.

Comment: I guess the only logical response to a question-that's-not-a-question is an answer-that's-not-an-answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace As with these other discussion posts (mentors, SOTV) it was asked to post questions in an answer.  With the excessive  comments, valid questions would be lost.

Comment: Meta isn't about questions. Get over it people. (sorry, couldn't refrain any longer)

Comment: @Shog9 Maybe best not to call it *hazing*, as that's illegal in some countries.

Comment: (Namely, the one out of which StackExchange operates)

Answer (score 17):

I won't comment here about the Spanish community manager job.

**I'm commenting here about the crazy idea you had to create a Stack Overflow website for 10 different languages. That really isn't a good idea IMO.**

I'm French, I always speak French, everyone at my job speaks French, but **we ALL JUST WANT ENGLISH WEBSITES to help us in our job**.

For example: as I'm working with Microsoft technologies, I spend a lot of time on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123401.aspx). MSDN in French is incomplete (at best) or auto-translated from English (80% of time). That's just crap. Everyone here now knows that you have to read/write English to be able to work efficiently. For my job, I don't want to Google things using *any other language than English*.

Creating Spanish SO, Russian SO...etc. will just fragment the whole thing and defeat the initial purpose of StackOverflow. SO is great because you have:

- some top notch contributors (Jon Skeet, Hans Passant, Eric Lippert...etc). I don't know their native language, but we (the vast majority of programming enthusiasts and professionals that can understand English at least just a bit) can read them thanks to the fact they use English
- thousands of specialists in any programming domain
- hundreds of thousands users that ask various questions and receive various answers for every possible programming issue every day
- the best programming Q/A database of the whole Internet

**Why would you change that? Having 10 different websites whould just reduce the overall expertise level and Q/A completeness of StackOverflow.**

It would just hide incredibly interesting questions/answers for the vast majority of us that read/write English but don't read/write Spanish/Russian/Chinese...etc.

For young beginners that start programming, I understand they're not supposed to read/write English. But there are others resources available online (tutorials etc.) in every possible language. *It doesn't have to be Stack Overflow* someone that doesn't speak a word of English should visit first.

Comment: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/ for the motivation. Simple, not every programming culture speaks English. There is no point in a Dutch Stack Overflow for example, the Dutch, as a people, have mastered English rather well. And just because *you* have mastered English, doesn't mean that others have or that there is a culture of learning English as part of learning to program.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I believe that is a misguided report to convince the community that we need to support SE's proprietary customers. Many of us do not buy it, including me. The whole report is fishy anyway, since it does not speak about the loss at all.

Comment: @lpapp: fine to speak for yourself, but don't claim to speak for a majority please.

Comment: I do not understand where that misguided assumption came from. I have never written _majority_. And I definitely can speak for the many people who already raised their objections, e.g. all answers here saying the same, pretty much. Submit a supporting answer, and we can finally start downvoting that. ^_^

Comment: @MartijnPieters - So, you are telling because the *Spanish* people don't want to learn english (which BTW is accepted *globally*), you create a *separate site*?. I don't have anything against the *spanish*, but this isn't right. What if tomorrow a million indians say we want SO to be in *hindi* (national language of India),chinese say we want it in chinese, japanese, finnish etc would you be Ok with that?

Comment: @TheLostMind: +1, I do not understand why it is a problem to learn a language to a minimum desired level that is the core of programming and many other things in the world these days. I am very bad at languages, yet I could learn English in no time for what I needed.

Comment: @TheLostMind: so you are of the opinion that creating per-language sites panders to a sub-culture that is too lazy to learn English. We'll all just have to talk loud and slow. Way to go for world peace and understanding!

Comment: @MartijnPieters - PS : Absolutely, no *disrespect* intended. I am afraid I would be waiting for an answer on SO while a person who knows the answer like [this guy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) would be waiting for questions somewhere else.

Comment: @ken2k : I think you can use a more descriptive [story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Babel) about what happen when peoples start to use different languages. It should be clearer.

Comment: We've had the argument about whether language-localised versions of SO should happen. Your side lost. Please accept that loss gracefully, and stop whinging every time non-English versions of SO are mentioned.

Comment: @TheLostMind: the problem is that when you cannot communicate in the same language no amount of being on the same site is going to make you understand one another.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I read the link you provided months ago, I still strongly disagree. I'm also really interested in knowing what are the **ten** programming cultures that doesn't speak English... while I could understand there could be one or two exceptions (maybe Japanese ?), why on earth Spanish? I would love to know what are the 4-6 under consideration that are not listed explicitly here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Also, don't forget programming is _tied_ to English for technical reasons: programming languages themselves are using English keywords. Official documentations comes in English first (if not _only_) for all main languages/framworks/products.

Comment: @TRiG Sorry, it's tagged _discussion_, so I'm discussing here. Giving my opinion, you know.

Comment: But you're saying nothing that hasn't been said a thousand times already. I'm allowed to express my frustration with boring discussion, aren't I?

Comment: @TRiG You totally are. You actually do, there's no problem with that.

Comment: I must confess that I do not have any idea what English or non-English has anything to do with "world peace".

Comment: @ken2k: it doesn't matter that the keywords are in English; learning keywords is very different from actually comprehending a language and you can get by just fine with only the keywords. There are tons of examples of loan words in just about every human language to testify to that, where people have entirely forgotten the word was taken from a different language.

Comment: @ken2k: And just because you cannot conceive of a culture where it is the norm to use your own language rather than learn English doesn't mean these things don't exist. To think that everyone should just learn English is, in my opinion, rather arrogant and short-sighted. I've now lived in 4 different countries with rather big differences in culture with multi-year spans in each, and the differences in outlook on issues locals take for granted are vast sometimes. And those were all western cultures, I can't imagine what living in any of the other continents might be like.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, but you're generalizing too much IMO. Programming is not the world, it's just programming. It's not about using English everywhere, it's about using the language that suits best the activity. For example, if you want to be astronaut, you'll have to learn Russian. Nobody wants to convert the world to Russian, it's just that the job requires that skill.

Comment: @ken2k: you have to learn russian until someone builds a space port in a different country where they speak a different language. Stack Overflow is building a spanish space port here.

Comment: @ken2k: yes, exactly. I completely agree. Even if there are some people not being able to learn the language (just assume it for a second), they should still not outrule what the majority does  on SO (understands English).

Comment: @ken2k: but you are still saying the rest of the world just has to get on with it and learn English, because that's just the way it is. That's the arrogant attitude I am referring to. It's easy for you, you already learned English after all.

Comment: @lpapp: you are making assumptions about programmers not speaking English being a small majority. What did you base those assumptions on?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: this is not really rocket science. SO (English) has had more users than any of the separate language sites altogether. Not to mention, I have also lived in several countries (more than four IIRC...), worked with several clients, etc. I think I have a bit of experience to be confident at claiming this. I am from a country where people _do not speak_ English that well like in Scandinavia, India, America, etc, but programmers do understand it anyhow. Coincidentally, I was in Spain last year, where we had >200-300 programmers understanding English, too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Let's continue with the Space example: you don't build your own station for your own country. There's already something called International Space Station, that happens to require you to speak Russian. If you really want to build your own Spanish air port, good, but please don't ask for the ISS people that happen to speak Spanish to migrate their efforts for the International one to the Spanish one. There are plenty of Spanish/French/XXX websites. Why does it _have to_ be the same for SO? Why fragmenting it?

Comment: That isn't even part of it @ken2k. Nobody is asking anyone to go to another site instead. If someone so wishes, they can participate on another side in another language as well. And for those who can't participate on an SO in English, there might be this useful site for them where they can ask their questions in the comfort of their own language. Are they better off learning English in the long run? Sure. But that doesn't imply programming information should only ever be offered in English.

Comment: @Bart Nobody's forcing anyone to do anything. But I honestly believe that having people ask their questions and provide their answers on their own website will just absorb a percentage of what could have been shared with the rest of the world through the unique SO.com website. Experts that are spending time on Spanish SO can't spend it on English SO. That's just fragmentation and dilution.

Comment: @ken2k I don't really see that risk being anywhere near significant to be honest. I've stated so before http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194959/do-the-benefits-of-having-so-in-multiple-languages-outweigh-the-risks-involved/194962#194962

Comment: @Bart People are lazy. I'm really convinced that a significant percentage of some XXX people would rather use a XXX website _even if they speak English_, just because it's easier. You know, you don't have to find the right translation of that weird localized error message you have...etc.

Comment: If it's lazy people we get rid of ...

Comment: @Bart We're not only getting rid of lazy people, we're also getting rid of their questions and the associated answers. That's not because a lazy person asks a question that the question is not interesting later for another person. If everyone made the effort to translate that weird localized error message in the _common language for programming_ (English), it would just be better and easier for everyone to google and find answers.

Comment: I don't really think it's reasonable to say to someone who wants to learn programming "You have to learn English first."  I mean, hey, I speak English as a native language, so no skin off my back.  But that's an artificial limitation and frankly I don't doubt that there are talented people with worthwhile contributions who simply don't speak English.

Comment: @emodendroket Of course, and it was my personal case more than 10 years ago, long before I started to use English. But it doesn't mean you _have to_ use one of the SE websites to start programming if you don't speak English. There are thousands of non-English websites that are about programming. But if you're a _professional or an enthusiast_, you really should start learning English at some point.

Comment: @ken2k So why's it better for them to be somewhere else instead of an SO spinoff?  Not like it solves the fragmentation problem.

Comment: @emodendroket Because it prevents active SO users to provide answers on other websites of the SE network.

Comment: @ken2k By what mechanism does it do that?  The English SO isn't being hidden.

Comment: @emodendroket People have a limited available amount of time, so the time spent on Spanish SO cannot be used on English SO. Adding more places to participate for the community mathematically reduces the time spent on a particular place.

Comment: I strongly disagree with you. There is a glaring hole in your reasoning: this initiative is targeted to people who don't know English enough to participate actively on Stack Overflow. They are *obviously* not part of the demographics of this site's active participants. If you like to think/code/write in English, fine. It's not everyone's option, though, nor a concern of *this* community if we launch a *different* community.

Comment: @Sklivvz For those that _ask questions_, I would say people are lazy and the effort to translate a question in English won't always be made if another site is available in a more native language. Now let's talk about the people that _answer questions_: don't you think that those that currently are part of SO community won't be tempted to spend some time on SO Spanish/FR/whathever is their native language? As previously said, people have a limited amount of time to spend on SE, and this time should be used IMO for a unique centralized EN website so a maximum amount of people can benefit from it

Comment: @ken2k your objection applies to *any site we launch*. Don't you think that the subset of developers who like cars aren't tempted to contribute to cars.se? Launching new sites has always had the overall effect of involving more people in the network and thus creating a larger pool of people which benefits everyone.

Comment: @ken2k A maximum amount of people that know english, you mean

Comment: @Sklivvz If I'm working on a code that doesn't work, I'm gonna ask a question. Now I would have to _choose_ between multiple sites, so I'll spend less time on the English one _for the time I'm allocating to fix my issue_. I won't spend time on cars.se while fixing my bug, it's an entirely different topic. Now for the people that answer questions (see my profile for example), I would have to balance time between, say, French SO and English SO. I've got a limited time to help people, so if I'm participating on French SO I won't participate as much on English SO. That's just maths.

Comment: It's incorrect maths. There are people for whom contributing here is not an option. Involving them certainly increases the number of available volunteers. You can keep all your effort on the English site if you want to. It's not a zero sum game.

Comment: @Sklivvz That's you way of doing maths, not mine. If a French SO comes to life, the time I'll spend on it will be time I won't spend on English SO, and I'm pretty sure of that.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: [You were saying?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023109/how-can-i-build-a-box-for-a-bed-and-breakfast-with-html-css-php) :P

Comment: @boltclock: oh dear. Always an exception. To be fair, that person is probably not even 13 yet, judging by the style and word choice.

Comment: @ken2k, you already have the option of asking on multiple sites. Stack Exchange has Stack Overflow, Programmers and Code Review - all programming related sites that target different aspects of the development process. How's your time management with dealing with those three sites?

Comment: "That's the stupidest idea I've ever seen on meta." is *really* unfair. Just speaking personally, I can think of *numerous* ideas I've proposed that were MUCH stupider than this one. :)

Comment: @ken2k Maybe you'll choose only one site, and I have to say that was my case. I barely contribute to SO after SOpt went live, because I chose so. Others chose to stick with SO and not contribute to SOpt at all. Turns out both sites are doing well, so what's the problem?

Comment: @Jaydles That _actually_ was unfair. I rephrased that part, I didn't mean to offend.

Comment: @ken2k, none taken!

Answer (score 13):

I don't know what all the negative comments are about. I'm Spanish, I love this site and would continue to use it in English regardless of having an equivalent community in Spanish, but that doesn't mean there aren't thousands upon thousands of people that struggle to communicate their problems in a language foreign to them and being able to contribute there would be great.

Probably I'll get downvoted for saying this, there are several people that said that English is compulsory and that in Spain we have a decent English level. I personally don't agree. There are many people with great written and oral English skills, but many more with mediocre English skills. I can't speak for the rest of the Spanish speaking people since I don't have that information readily available.

I've been giving Android talks for three years now at a university in Madrid and actually questioned my students about the reason for not actively using stackoverflow as an aid for studying. The response, with a few exceptions, was unanimous  **They don't feel comfortable enough to ask and convey what they're trying to say**, and in most cases, they end up trying snippets of code from other answers and asking the teachers.

I totally support this initiative and I think it will have a great positive impact.
<strike>I would apply for this, but I don't live in the US.</strike> I applied for this but couldn't change the country so I'll assume it will get dismissed.

Comment: Juan, most of the team is remote, so not living in the US isn't a problem!

Comment: @Jaydles when I try to apply, on the second step it request a US address and I don't see a country dropdown or anything :)

Comment: thanks for the heads up. We'll get that fixed.  For now, feel free to just fill in your address- we'll ignore the country.

Comment: Juan, tell your students about their uncertain future if they go out from university without mastering english and the limitation they suffer if they can not learn from scientific literature. I agree with you about the bad english level of Spaniards (mine the worst) but, for a professional, english fluency is nowadays a must, a requirement, in nearly all technical and scientific areas. Now the world is global and english the lingua franca. Your students must be able to exchange ideas with people outside the small room of the class.

Comment: @joaquin, totally agree but in the meantime there is nothing wrong with being able to ask those questions in spanish. They can improve their english and while they do so, ask in spanish until they feel comfortable

Comment: If they do not need to do the efford they will not try until too late.

Comment: @Jaydles I applied, although there'll be people with prettier cvs and greater experience, still worth a try

Answer (score 12):

I am a native spanish speaker, and english is my third or fourth language. I believe that SO in spanish (and in other languages as well) is a wonderful tool and will become an invaluable resource for the spanish speaking community.

I already posted, a couple of years ago to the [Why are some people just not that interested in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47501/why-are-some-people-just-not-that-interested-in-stack-overflow/125722#125722) question, an answer very relevant here. So let me reproduce it:

---

*In my environment some people just don't jump into SO because of their knowledge and proficiency (or lack of) on the english language.*

*They are affraid to ask, shy to respond, feel embarrased with the need to explain themselves.. They either just don't take it, or give up after a few attempts and never follow on.*

*For many, they'd love SO in their language.*

---

And I believe that it will bring value back to SO in english as well. Because many of us, spanish speakers and contributors to SO in english, will participate in both SO and SO-es, and will ensure that interesting and fresh questions and answers get linked between both sites.

Comment: No native english speaker made me feel dumb cause of my english, in contrary!!! I think, there are more spanish people, laugh other spanish people cause of their english than native english speakers, who laugh cause of it. Therefore I think, many spaniards are very complexed about their english, Regards

Comment: I am a native English speaker. I find that most people who say their English is "terrible" are much better at making themselves understood than they seem to think. It is usually the people who _don't_ tell us their English is terrible who have the worst English. In both cases, we try to not hold the lack of good English against them. English skill is not, after all, a sign of intelligence!

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but don't forget that, like a good psycological thriller, the reality is suspended and what remains is the perceived fear.

Comment: Could you offer a hand with this: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28330370/revisions

Answer (score 8):

I'm Brazilian but I rarely visited the Portuguese site because the English site traffic is much bigger and I can effectively read and write English. But most Brazilians can't hence the Portuguese site success. My guess is that most [native Spanish speakers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_language) also can't communicate effectively in English so I expect another success.

Comment: From what I see on your SO profile, it would be great for [pt.so] if you could drop by and post an answer from time to time. Just saying... :)

Comment: @bfavaretto My specialization is PostgreSQL and the traffic is so low that I would need to visit everyday for a week or two to have a chance to find an interesting question. With that said I just posted an answer there :)

Answer (score 8):

When we talk about the danger of Balkanization, there's another form of Balkanization we have to take into account as well.  I'm thinking of divides not only along cultural/language lines but also of a divide along socioeconomic lines.  What's said about all computer professionals or enthusiasts having a working knowledge of English is true enough, as long as you limit yourself to the professional class.

But computing and even programming is no longer limited to the professional class.  There are people in the third world who are barely literate, but who are becoming computer literate, and who might benefit by being able to ask questions and receive answers in their own language. A Spanish language SO would, I think, help some subset of those people.  They may have enough English skills to tackle a manual, but not enough to phrase a question clearly enough in English.  The same goes for answers.

The distinction between the professional class and the humbler classes is much more marked in the third world than it is in the first world.

I'm not worried about English SO losing valuable answers due to the existence of a Spanish alternative.  The vast majority of participants in English SO will continue to participate.  A few people will probably participate in both English and Spanish SO.  The prior experience with Portuguese should prove instructive here.

Answer (score 8):

For some background: I am a native Spanish speaker from Lima, Peru. My English is sufficiently good for both technical and non-technical communication. I "studied" English in school and even in kindergarten, but was never a particularly good student, to put it mildly. Only when I took programming as a hobby and was confronted with the unavailability of good enough learning resources in Spanish, did I come to terms with the fact that not learning English was not an option. So I can put myself in the shoes of someone who needs to ask a programming question, but whose English is not good enough to use the international Stack Overflow site.

Now, to cut straight to the point: Yes, there is value in making Stack Overflow available to people who are not proficient enough in English to use the international Stack Overflow site. However, even then, I think we need to encourage non-English-speaking programmers to learn written English little by little, so that they can eventually make use of the by far vaster resources available in this language. If a Spanish version of Stack Overflow helps spread both programming *and* English knowledge, I would love to contribute to it.

---

I think I fulfill most, if not all the requirements posted above:

1. **Fluency in English and Spanish (native-level *writing* in Spanish)**

   Besides being a native Spanish speaker, my written English skills are top-notch (no immodesty intended, just check my Stack Exchange profiles) and my spoken English is also quite good, although my pronunciation is obviously not native to anyone who hears me.
2. **Enough programming experience or training to be the only moderator / company liaison to the community on a Spanish-language Stack Overflow (at least at first)**

   I am no beginner programmer - I am familiar with several technologies, both mainstream and now-rather-niche-but-very-promising. And, most importantly, I love programming well (separating concerns, isolating errors, etc.) and teaching others how to do it, which I think is important for a site many people will use as a learning and reference resource.
3. **Experience using Stack Exchange sites (huge rep is *not* required, but we want someone who gets and loves the system.)**

   Although lately I have not been terribly active, my profile and reputation attest to the fact I know very well how Stack Overflow is meant to be used.
4. **Comfort owning and overseeing a multi-step plan. International site rollouts involve a fair bit of planning, and each one is different. You'd be responsible (with help from a senior CM) for establishing and overseeing execution of a rollout plan.**

   I have never worked specifically on an international site, but as a software professional, I have been involved in the rollout of large projects.

Answer (score 8):

Coming from a third world country (Dominican Republic) where the population is far behind in terms of English knowledge, yet has seen a surge of interest in programming and software developing, i can guarantee you that an Spanish S.O would be extremely helpful.

I've been working at a small software developing company for the past year. Right now we have 3 new "pupils" who recently began pursuing a career in development. However their English knowledge its minimal. Whenever they are asking questions about how to do this or that, i feel propel to point them to SO to get help from the same place i had gotten so much help in the past year. However, even though the answers to their questions its right in front of their eyes, its impossible for them to use it to their advantage, mainly because instructions are in English. This, among other factors, makes me believe that a Spanish SO would be an awesome idea.

I'm a native Spanish speaker, and my English its good enough. I believe i do have moderating skills and could fare well in this position.. If only i had more programming reputation :p

Answer (score 8):

I see this as an encouraging sign that computing is maturing as a field of study. Typically, when a subject is getting started, all the information is published in only one or two languages, and you learn something of at least one of those languages in order to participate.

For example, if you wanted to understand the latest work in physics in Newton's time, you had better be able to read Latin - his most important work was originally published under the title "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica". At the time, the community of European physicists was too small to support separate publication in each language.

Normally, as a subject matures, more work is published in or translated into more languages, making the subject accessible without the burden of learning a specific natural language in order to study it. It is now possible to study physics in many languages.

For computer programming, that starting language was English, with some competition from German for theory. Should that really mean every computer programmer for all time should be expected to learn English? Someday, there will be enough programmers in the world to support publication and discussion in many different languages. SO seems to think that time has come, and they may well be right.

Answer (score 7):

This is great...should definitely be done. Roughly 30% of my jobs consists of translating SO posts for those coworkers who aren't proficient enough in English to do it on their own.

Most coders here in Peru are of a technical level, with a two or three year "degree" that gives them just enough knowledge to start working, and the brunt of actual training is done on the job; however, the majority don't speak English or are only able to mechanically identify key words in whatever programming language they learned.

You might say then "why don't they go to Spanish-speaking fora"...there's the rub. They do go on Spanish fora, but the technical level there is pretty low, since the "standard" language for programming is English (and Russian to a degree) so the really tough questions are out of their reach in those fora.

They know of SO and try to use it, but the language barrier is too much. The issue is that high-level coders don't trust random fora around, but they do trust SO, so seeing a Spanish forum here would bridge the gap between them.

Answer (score 5):

It's a great thing for me, I have a good level of English but having it in my own language would help me to focus on my problem; so I suppose this to be the same for native-Spanish speakers ... ah, I have got 75% of requirements, use to live in Spain and I speak Spanish (not native) as well

Comment: `but having it in my own language would help me to focus on my problem`: what about the persons who speak English and a native language different of yours?

Answer (score 5):

I think a site in Spanish should succeed and it could actually encourage people to learn and/or improve another language. For those who speak natively Spanish and are willing to learn English and vice versa.

The mere fact that Spanish is the second language by number of speakers in the world [Wikipedia: List of languages by number of native speakers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers), after Mandarin, should suffice as a good reason for this enterprise to be successful.

I can foresee the following challenges:

- **Language Fragmentation**: Spanish is actually a designation for Spanish from Castilla + the additions from different countries where the language is spoken. When I started programming 25+ years ago one of the major difficulties was to translate for several countries. The words Software and Hardware were the easiest: to this day, I believe that not even in Spain we have a word for those terms, so we ended up not doing so. File and Computer were a very interesting ones. Books from Spain translated them as "Fichero" and "Ordenador" and Books translated in Latin American (typically "Méjico") used "Archivo" and "Computador". So we learned both ways. I think the problems started when we tried to translate Hash, Gateway, Reboot and other terms where the translations were out of of touch. It was so bad that some of us ended up using some Spanglish term like rebutiar (reboot), los mouse (the mice), etc. I think in this case the language was used again for what is fundamentally the reason of them: communication. In actuality, English does the same, we used both Moon and Lunar, Lung and pulmonary and Street and avenue, some from the old English and combination with some from Latin, Greek, Spanish, French, etc. I believe that people are going to find the way to deal with the differences, the same way we manage to resolve the differences among Colombians (I was born there), Puerto Ricans, Dominicans, Mexicans, etc. In the end, given our nature it's difficult to find jerks in our communities, most of the time we have fun when we have to translate "Spanish to Spanish", and the Jerks, if any, have a really bad time with us. '!Qúe viva el Español!
- **Stack Overflow Fragmentation**: It may be possible but very unlikely. Google and StackOverflow itself are evolving multilingual ecosystems. Therefore Search Engines, links created between posts, translation engines and Artificial Intelligence (AI) are going to assist us more and more. Of course, communities and their natural desire to help each other are going to play an critical role. I believe most people are not going to mind some corrections/annotations and far more important, people are going to be willing to create the gateway, bridge or router between communities.

Well, you native English speakers probably already realized that English was not my native language :-) but that's exactly the spirit, when I came to USA, Kernel was the Unix layer, Windows was the OS and Shell was the Oil Company, but nowadays I am able to navigate both languages with flexibility. This, of course is because Spanish is a very rich language (Music, TV, Food, etc) that is able to co-exist pacifically with other languages.

In summary, I cannot find any reason why we cannot add Programming to the Spanish Language Repertoire (another from Latin/French!).

I am not looking for a Job, but I am willing to help: I am fluent in English and Spanish both business and technical. I am also acquainted with French and Italian. Acquainted! s'il vous plaît don't start a conversación in quelle lingue :-).

Finally, I almost forgot to mention my fluency in C, C++, C#, and other tools that are not so relevant anymore ;-)

Good luck!

> Don Corleone: I have a sentimental weakness for my children and I
>   spoil them, as you can see. They talk when they should listen. Anyway,
>   Signor Sollozzo, my no is final and I wish to congratulate you on your
>   new business and I'm sure you'll do very well and good luck with that.
>   Especially since your interests don't conflict with mine. Thank you.

*Mario Puzo. The Godfather.*

Comment: No one's help will be required :) but input from someone like you sure will be welcome once we get going!

Comment: Good catch! I'm going to remove the "it is required" ;-)

Comment: @GonzaloContento : `I think a site in Spanish should succeed and it could actually encourage people to learn and/or improve another language` Ok, by this way you will also love to learn/improve`Turkish; Armenian; Albanian; German; Greek; Lithuanian; Latvian; Dutch; Afrikaans; Czech; Polish; Slovak; Vietnamese; Khmer; Mandarin; Korean; Indonesian; Bengali; Tamil; Uzbek; Nepali; Persian; Dzongkha`in order to find the informations you want on SO.

Comment: @user2284570 Not sure what your point is/was... The question was related to the Spanish Language. And yes, about other languages: why not? The Internet can carry as much information as we are able to consume. It is exactly when data becomes information that we perceive its value.

Comment: @GonzaloContento : One of the  goal of SO was to build a good database of knowlwedge splitting it into several languages that peoples won’t be able to read *(which is sure to append compared to english)* break it.

Answer (score 5):

I am Argentine and here spanish spoken, but very little English. Public education only teaches a very basic English that is useless for technical matters. My level of English is terrible like many of my coworkers.

But we all use Stack Overflow anonymously for years. And without an intermediate level of English, it is impossible to actively participate. Often wanted to share knowledge but could not for the language barrier. Simply it take to much time to answer. Many times I wanted to ask a question and did not know how to be clear.

SO in Spanish, will be a great site for that people that spoken only spanish can participate.

I think it's a wonderful idea.

GRACIAS AMIGOS!

Comment: `Public education only teaches a very basic English that is useless for technical matters`Do they teach a correct Japanese and Mandarin?

Comment: @user2284570 no, just verb to be, do and does and cat means "gato'.

Comment: The same way, I learned English French and Deutche but not Spanish. The same way you won’t be able to find informations on hypothetical French SO *(which is likely to be not on the English site in the future because most informations would be on natives languages SO sites)*.

Answer (score 4):

This job looks perfect for me. I'm a developer experienced with a a big variety of computer languages like assembly, C, C++, Ruby, Java, Perl, Php, PLSQL and so on. I also have experience with different platforms like Linux, Windows, MacOS, Aix, Solaris, netbsd, etc.

I'm Brazilian, but I lived in Madrid for 15 years and now I'm in UK. I worked my whole life as a trainer in Spain, and I also have the DELE certification (Spanish certification).

I also have experience reviewing technical books and I just started writing my first book (a Swift book).

I've been using SO for 2 years, and also asked and replied questions on other stack exchange sites, like server fault and DBA.

Answer (score 3):

As a native spanish speaker I have had mixed feelings about having "localized" versions of StackOverflow.

Being an enthusiast of StackOverflow as the best community-driven/curated knowledge base, I used to think that it was a terrible idea to split the *lingua franca* knowledge base (the original SO) into a big one base with a few "*impure*" satellites.

However, at least in Spain, there is an inconvenient truth/fact:

- *Generally speaking, **we have below average English skills***. This [map](http://jakubmarian.com/map-of-the-percentage-of-people-speaking-english-in-the-eu-by-country/) showing the percentage of the population being able to hold a conversation in English was quite popular in Spanish online/offline media as a confirmation of our poor English skills.

Besides, there are many Spanish communities related with technology: [javaHispano](http://www.javahispano.org), [linuxHispano](http://www.linuxhispano.net), etc. targeting all the Spanish speaking countries.

There is even a ["stackOverflow-Spanish"-alike web](http://entredesarrolladores.com), showing that there many developers willing to have a localized version of StackOverflow. As an example, in the welcome post in March 2013, there is a comment saying that:

> "Felicitaciones por este proyecto, espero que se conviertan en el
>   StackOverflow hispano"
>
> ---
>
> "Congratulations on this project, I hope you will become the Spanish StackOverflow".

Summing up, there are people willing to have a Spanish StackOverflow and as [Renan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2263584/renan) pointed out in his answer, the key for a successful Spanish StackOverflow (or for any othe language) is that we can develop some good communications channels/patterns between the main StackOveflow and the localized versions.

Taking all the above into account, I no longer think the Spanish Stack Overflow is such a bad idea :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Portugal, and I'm willing to help the ptSO, if you guys from SO think that's a good idea just tell me. I already have online moderation experience in some websites.

Comment: Hey dippas, just visit [pt.so], the site is open to the public.

Comment: Ya I'm aware of that, that's why I say that I'm available to help the ptSO on moderation

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of the posts are missing a very important part of the issue: Community.

It's true that most of us, that already speak English good enough to use and participate on SO, probably won't use esSO for finding answers. And I also agree that for any developer to have a good level of english is a very important skill.

But I am pretty sure that there are millions of non-english speakers that use SO to find answers anyway, because they have enough level to read some english or at least to read code (I know many!). And it's that group of people, a passive group of SO users, that are not part of the community, who will automatically jump to the localized one.

To me SO is much much more than a simple Questions and Answers site, and is that why I think this proposal make so much sense, it will give the opportunity to this group of people to be part of the SO community using their own language.

I agree that it's very important to avoid knowledge fragmentation, but all this people that are not asking or answering for fear of not being understood are loosing their chance of being part of SO, and that means that we are actually losing knowledge, that's even worse than fragmentation. I also think that there's going to be a lot of people willing to translate questions to another languages (I will happily do it!, we can have a new set of badges for this :D!) so in the end fragmentation will just be a temporal issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that people need to think deeper than "Everybody speaks English, SO en Español would be useless".

To make it clear, I would vote YES to the proposition of creating a Spanish SO. I am originally from Mexico City, and I lived there for some time. My point is that, for those who have not had the possibility to study English as a second language, SO en Español could be very beneficial. For example, Mexico City is the biggest city in the world (extension-wise) and believe it or not, some public schools do not even require students to take a second language as part of their core education. And I am not only talking about middle schools or high schools, but public colleges that are guided towards Engineering and Sciences as well. And this is only Mexico city, which is the most developed city in Mexico. In other regions of the country, not only STEM related students but also students in general struggle to learn a second language due to economic hardship and other reasons. That was only a one-country example. What about the rest of the latin american countries? Spanish (Spain) nationals who are in the same situation? I must emphasize that SO en Español might be useless for those who at least might have a very basic knowledge of English, but it would be gold to those who have not had the chance to learn it and can only speak Spanish. SO en Español would reach out to those kind of people who, believe me, are out there and are not just two or three hundred people.

I am in the best disposition to help if you guys need anything, like translating stuff or something.

Just my two cents here!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

i speak spanish as native language but i think the same as others comment here:

for example :

- Having English as language for the comunity will benefit the largest possible number of people.
- The code, sdks, methods, etc are primarily in english.
- English it's the main technical language for programmers and software engineers.

Personally don´t agree with a new Spanish Stackoverflow, well i never thought to have a Portuguese Stack Overflow!  ಠ_ಠ

Personally I´m not afraid of or it doesn´t affect me but
Why we need the same question in Spanish?
We must close the Question with "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." or with ""Esta pregunta se ha hecho antes y ya tiene una respuesta." "

Well probably in the future we could have Stack Overflow in Russian/Chinese/Huichol/Mazahua/Kinyarwanda/Czech/Javanese...

Hey! I´d like to have an Stack Overflow in javanese! =)

Quiero Javanes!

Answer (score -1):

### SPANISH

Por que hacerlo tan complicado?

Aquí hay otro plan.

1. Las preguntas se pueden hacer en cualquier idioma. Indicando y/o Detectando Cual.
2. La Audiencia selecciona el idioma o los idiomas que prefiere ver.
3. Si Alguien que lee preguntas en español y sabe ingles, cree que es una buena pregunta, la traduce bien, de forma clara y obtiene alguna reputación por hacerlo. Esto evitaría que usuarios como yo vayamos al traductor de Google. Subiría la Calidad y Claridad de las Preguntas por que la gente que no sabe ingles, puede preguntar en su lengua madre, donde piensa con claridad.
4. Lo mismo aplica a las respuestas.
5. Así Tendríamos un único StackOverflow.

Si alguien cree que es una buena idea, por favor traducir abajo. No recibirá +2 por que estamos en Meta ;). Pero el traductor de Google hizo un desastre con este texto.

Gracias

### ENGLISH

Why make it so complicated?

Here's another plan.

1. Questions can be in any language, indicating and/or (automatically) detecting which one.
2. Users select the language(s) they prefer to see.
3. If someone sees a question in Spanish and knows English, and believes that it's a good question, they can translate it clearly, and earn some reputation for doing so. This will prevent users like me from (having to go /) going to Google Translate. The quality and clarity of questions would increase because people who don't know English can ask in their mother tongue, where they think more clearly.
4. The same applies to answers.
5. Thus we would have a single, unified Stack Overflow.

If someone thinks this is a good idea, please translate the above. You won't receive +2 because we're on Meta. ;) But Google Translate is a disaster with this text.

Thanks.

Comment: We did discuss this approach, but it's much harder in two ways: the more important is that it would be pretty much impossible to guarantee a critical mass in every language, so that every question and answer *did* get translated. Secondly, designing an interface that allows multiple languages for content (and the interface itself), and building in mechanics for evaluating the correctness of a translation, becomes very, very messy very quickly.

Comment: @Laura muchas gracias! entiendo. no me sorprende que ya lo hallan pensado. thank you very much! I understand. no wonder they are already thought.

Comment: I think the big problem is that people who do not know an answer tend to misunderstand the question.  And people who misunderstand the question are very likely to mistranslate it.  Translating answers is less problematic.

Answer (score -1):

Funny how this job does NOT use careers.stackexchange.com, but is in Jobvite instead. I'll consider applying anyway, as it tickles my curiosity.

Comment: Victor, glad you're applying! It's only in Jobvite because (today) Careers is only set up for Developer or SA roles, so we can't easily use it for Community Manager ones, even though we're often hiring devs in that space.

Answer (score -4):

For a moment, let's set aside the *language* part and concentrate on the actual question. 
**Fluent in Spanish? We're hiring a Community Manager for a Spanish Stack Overflow**. This is certainly a question which should be posted on a Job portal (`careers 2.0 ?`). The question is *clearly* a job posting. So, it should be closed.

Next, coming back to the language part and the actual idea behind this question, I feel that it's really bad. Currently, thousands of people whose native language is **not** English (I am one of them) come on SO (SE) to ask / answer questions. Language has never been a barrier here and it should remain that way.

**The problem with Spanish SO?**
Many people who know Spanish *might* prefer to go and answer questions there. So, there is a pretty good chance that the same question might get answer on *Spanish SO* and not on *(English) SO*. You are creating a nuisance where none exists.

Comment: Have you got any _data_ supporting this "_thousands of people whose native language is not English...Language has never been a barrier here and it should remain that way._"?

Comment: @Omar: evidence does not need data IMHO. If they cannot read language manuals anad docs written in English, they will be terribly lost in the IT world.  Can you show any useful programmer without understanding those? I am not a native speaker, yet looking back at my 5-6 years old posts, I did get the stuff even if my grammar was not completely correct. Having said that, I do agree it may help some people, but surely we lose out more than we gain. Therefore, English brings more to the world overall.

Comment: @Omar-  I've seen several hundred questions in which the OP mentions *English is not my native language*. These questions were not judged based on the OP's *language*, they were judged based on their content.

Comment: @TheLostMind : I think you can use a more [descriptive story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Babel) aout what append when peoples start to use different languages. It should be clearer.

Comment: @TheLostMind and many of them were closed "_unclear what you're asking_".

Comment: +1000. If you are a specialist in a programming topic, chances are you *know* how to speak English. In which case, I want your expertise on SO. I don't want to learn that a tricky issue was solved on pt.so or another language so site, and not on SO. You have 100+ Stack Exchange sites, most of them would benefit greatly from localization (money, cooking, ...). Pick one. Any one, but SO.

Comment: @Omar - They might have been closed because the content of the question (and not the language used) was unclear. I can give you several examples and you will come back with more supporting your point. Yes, I agree there *might* have been cases where the OP's english was too poor to understand but in most cases, I've seen people editing questions / answers to make them better.

Comment: @VonC - Exactly. *Programming* itself has grown beyond the barriers posed by natural languages. This question is winding time backwards.

Comment: The Area 51 proposals for these site have reached the criteria for launch, therefore SE **has** to do all it can to get these sites launched.

Comment: +10000000 @VonC to you too

Comment: @ChrisF - But did *they* think about the negative impact of this ?

Comment: @TheLostMind: something whispers me SE got a stubborn Spanish customer ($), and it is not done for the love of the community. It is likely about politics than evolution.

Comment: We've had the argument about whether language-localised versions of SO should happen. Your side lost. Please accept that loss gracefully, and stop whinging every time non-English versions of SO are mentioned.

Comment: I'm with you. Is there going to be an English post on English-SO created with every foreign language thread, at the same time? What if it's flagged? Will it be closed/flagged/etc on every different language SO site? What if I go to Google a question, and there's only a Spanish answer and I don't understand it? +1 to the folks who pointed out **all documentation is initially written in (sometimes only) English**.

Comment: @OverMind "What if I go to Google a question, and there's only a <language I don't understand> answer and I don't understand it?"

Comment: @Lamak I do speak some Spanish, however, being politically correct; your wording trumps mine, and you are correct. That's what I should have written. Adding on, though - is SO going to convert all popular questions to <insert language here> SO ? Or will there be overlap, but because it's a different language it's alright?

Comment: @OverMind - Of course there's gonna be an overlap. People would rather ask a question on their *native SO* instead of looking for it on English SO.

Comment: @TheLostMind That kind of throws the idea for SO to be a **unified knowledge bank** for programming/coding questions aside. If I have a problem regarding X, and there is an answer in <insert foreign language here> and not in English, SO wouldn't carry the same fairness that it does now.

Comment: @OverMind - Unfortunately, very few people see it that way..

Comment: @OverMind "fairness"?, so it's not fair that an answer is not in english?, but it's totally fair that another user that doesn't understand english can't benefit from that post?

Comment: @OverMind generally speaking, the onus is on the message creator to ensure proper transmission of the message. because lamak misunderstood your poorly-constructed syntax, you should consider re-wording and not simply insulting him.

Comment: @OverMind "I applaud your brain's ability to formulate what I said ..." is a back-handed "compliment." Don't pretend that it wasn't. If you want to get into message parsing here, I'll gladly illustrate how I arrived at this conclusion, but I'd rather you edit your comment

Comment: @VerMind *"I am saying if I have a question, and there's a thread on SO regarding it, but the answer isn't in English, how is that benefitting the general public, when code is in English?"* It's not. it's benefiting the public that speaks that (other) language. The same holds true for **all** English SO sites. They are **not** benefiting the general public. They are benefiting the English speaking public.

Comment: @OverMind "Code" isn't in english (even if most of the commands and syntax uses english words), it's still in a programming language. The formulation of the question and the answer may be in another language, but not really the code

Comment: @ypercube Let me state that I am not 100% against it - these are just thoughts I am having. So going with your statement - SO is not beneficial to a general public who speak another language. That's what you are saying? Is there evidence to prove this? Of course someone who speaks ONLY Chinese or ONLY Portuguese won't be able to understand portions of a question or an answer, but what percentage of those people are programmers?  Maybe this will [help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202723/coding-in-other-spoken-languages).

Comment: @OverMind No, that is not what I'm saying, of course. I'm just saying that English SO is not benefiting the general public. It's benefiting only the English speakers, even those that have basic knowledge. But there are others that do not understand English at all. Or understand a bit but not enough to post an understable question. It's the other way around, too. SO cannot be helped by those that are great programmers but not have English knowledge. We are missing some great answers by them. Why not provide them a site they can do this?

Comment: As for the percentage of programmers speaking English, I'm sure it varies from country to country. In Greece and Netherlands, a large percent of the population understands at least basic English but I wouldn't say that for Italy or Spain or Tunisia. I have no idea about Japan or China but I'd bet it's not high either, even among programmers. Do you have any statistics about this?

Comment: @ypercube The last 2 sentences make me understand your point a lot better. A counter to your statement, though; It's no different if a question I Google is posted in a foreign language I don't understand, is it? Is a Q&A in X language that benefits 5% of visitors to SO worth a site in X language? Would there be a conscious effort to somehow convert that language to English if it is *that* valuable to the community? If you posted a great answer regarding searching reg ex in SQL Server, but it was in Greek - how is that benefitting the community majority? Will all good questions be converted?

Answer (score -4):

I would NEVER go to StackOverflow in spanish. I'm argentinian, living in Spain for the time being. And that would be terrible. I get there is a large amount of people that don't know english in Spain, but the percentage of those people among programmers is almost `null`. I mean, how can you program **whatever** and not know english!?!

Besides, how many experts do we have in spanish? How many really good employees from really good companies speak spanish? We wouldn't even have 1% of the "pros" we have in SO. So, when it comes to reliability on the answer, and even speed on comments, I would pick the original-english-allmighty-SO before any other.

That's my oppinion though, feel free to comment ;)

**EDIT:** I just had an idea, comment it bellow.

I think the solution would be to hire translators, to translate one non-english-speaking-person's question to the original (english) SO, and vice-versa if needed. Furthermore, I think we should accept non-english answers in the original, and let the community handle the translation process. We have here plenty of people to do that. We can even translate back the answers! This way we keep all the precious "brain" here, while attending to people with needs *outside* the english language.

Comment: I'm argentinian too and i think the same. English is the "de facto" language for programming related questions, and by this we have questions and answers from all around the world, and that is precisely the strength of this site. Creating and SO Spanish/Portuguese/Russian/Chinense/etc version, it's a totally nonsense IMHO.

Comment: i'm argentinian but disagree. The Spanish is before English as an international language in Latin America. Latin America is the weakest of all regions on english spoken. This site can enhance the level of Hispanic speakers programmers.

Comment: @rnrneverdies I beg to differ. While I realize this might be true in case of the general population, I don't think those statistics hold for the subset of educated population. And a programmer, up to a point, has at least basic education in his/her poket. Besides, I'm not saying that we **can't** have a spanish SO, I'm just saying it's not going to be nearly as **useful**, **reliable** or **concurred** as the original. And also it's going to take "brain" away from the original, to put it somewhere else.

Comment: "the subset of educated population".. jaajaa... xenophobia 100%.

Comment: Anyway, there are other topics besides programming, ripe for using an stack site: cooking, parenting, politics, literature… just to name a few.

Comment: @VictorJalencas - It doesn't talk here about SE in spanish, just SO. If that's the case, then by all means. Although we're still losing people here...

Comment: I agree that it's almost impossible to be a programmer without knowing english, but directing efforts toward spanish programming communities aims to make it possible.

Answer (score -5):

[Tanenbaum](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum) argues his books are translated into 2 different editions in Spanish one for Spain and other for Latin American countries.

[[image]

<sub>(source: [cs.vu.nl](http://www.cs.vu.nl/~ast/book_covers/CN-2-mexican.jpg))</sub>](http://www.cs.vu.nl/~ast/book_covers/CN-2-mexican.jpg)

[[image]

<sub>(source: [cs.vu.nl](http://www.cs.vu.nl/~ast/book_covers/CN-3-mexican.jpg))</sub>](http://www.cs.vu.nl/~ast/book_covers/CN-3-mexican.jpg)

I don't know whether it happens in Portugal's and Brazil's Portuguese, but there are several computer related semes that have different words in both sides of the "pond". Some words are even taboo in some countries (such as *coger*)

This should be handled/managed by the candidate.

Comment: No, I think this should be handled by the community. About 50% of everyday's terms and expressions in Portugal are sexual slangs in Brazil (don't ask), yet Portuguese speakers around the world get along just fine. I speak Spanish and I think the fact that what is a beak to some is a penis to others has never caused any problems here in South America.

Comment: Coger is like F@ck in english! ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Elenasys but only in some Spanish speaking countries.  In other it just means "take".

Answer (score -12):

**Make a proper clone that is translated into any language** - not a whole separate page!

Why don't you just rely on the community with back and forth translation of content? There is so many of us who speak many different languages and would happily help to offer a translation of the main SO content?

Why not make this a new feature? Make this a part of the gamification system.

There are plenty of people who would happily click a <kbd>TRANSLATE</kbd> button and help with translation of contents.

No need for a completely new site in a different language. Let's all collaboratively work to translate contents. Click your country flag to see the page in your mother language.

Throw a few badges to reward the *translators*.

**but**

keep everything in English primarily- **don't separate the contents, don't separate us.**. Make this just an option for anyone to chose the language layer of SO. I don't speak Spanish so I can't benefit from all the great questions and answers people would post on their "own" site.

**and 1 mod vs. the whole community**

another argument is 1 Spanish moderator ain't enough for the entire Spanish Community. With the amount of native Spanish speaking users I guess we could *easily* get content translated. People could offer bounties to translate etc... You already have the *tools* necessary to provide the SO content in Spanish - you've got a huge and great community of multiple nations - use *that* to translate the content and please **don't separate us.**

Comment: SOpt started out with only one mod, now it has a handful. More mods should be added to SOes as the community grows.

Comment: Also, as for having a unique multilingual SO, with a translation game: that would cause multiple translation wars. And if you think nowadays people complain of the volume of crap questions that show up in SO, imagine if you had a lot of questions in foreign languages appearing in the first page...

Comment: @Renan all SE is doing here is just taking all the crap from the front page and splitting it across different sites. The crap will still be there just in another language, under a different web address...

Answer (score -12):

I do not see any problem if the site will be built such a way that you can easily switch from your native language site to the English (original) site. Moreover the same question can be asked in the both sites.

If you need a Russian speaking community manager then you may set eyes on me

Answer (score -14):

Stack Overflow on Spanish? I honestly think that nobody will use it. I'm Spanish and I know that here in my country a lot of people understand English (in fact, is a compulsory subject on school since the three years until the eighteen). Furthermore, English is the official language of science and technology, so people who is interested on programming can speak it. I'm just a sixteen years old boy, but I think that this is what a lot of Spanish native speakers from Spain and South America think.

Comment: [_it's very difficult todo esto.._](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Gz0n4kf0Olw) Science is not exclusive for one group, any kind of knowledge should be shared amongst all nations with no barriers whatsoever.

Comment: English in Science and Technology? Nobody will use it. Yes, that's what many people thought several centuries ago, when they used Latin as Lingua Franca for Science and Technology and take a look around now.

Comment: Hello dad, I am nobody ;)

Comment: nobody here too

Comment: You do know that it got proposed in Area 51 first, right?, and that it reached the required number of commited users

Comment: I was just giving my opinion as native Spanish speaker but I see that anybody agrees with me...

Comment: In general terms, I agree with you.

Comment: @Omar Spaniards, we don't deserve our politicians. You show a counterexample of the actual situation in research centers, bio and tech companies.

Comment: @Gödel77 So what do you think it will be the main IT language for the next twenty years or so. Maybe Occitan ?  or Chinese ?. Because we, Spaniards, we do not plan a new Imperial outburst in the next few years. Can not promess anything after that period :-)

Comment: @joaquin Why do you say that about 20 years? English has not too become Science and Technology Lingua Franca in 20 years, so, why do you ask anything like this?  Regards

Comment: @Gödel I understood your reference as a historical irony. What I was saying is wherever the lingua franca is in the next century, for the next 20-30 years english is and will be the reference for S&T. So it is difficult to understand a student of professional not being able to exchange ideas in that language and have this interchange reduced to the limited environment of your specific country language.

Comment: @joaquin. Ha, ha, Occitane. Well, according to the current attitude of the Catalan government, you could be forgiven for thinking that Catalan was the future language of science and technology.

Answer (score -34):

I'd like to submit my application for this job.

## Requirements

> Fluency in English and Spanish (native-level writing in Spanish)

I'm not quite fluent in Spanish but I'm willing to learn. I think this should only be a minor setback. [Rosetta Stone](http://www.rosettastone.com/) is discounted to $249 now so the company expense would be minimal. They guarantee I can learn it *very* quick.

When it comes to English, I have a stellar reputation on [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/14451/evan-carroll) too.

> Enough programming experience or training to be the only moderator / company liaison to the community on a Spanish-language Stack Overflow (at least at first)

My reputation precedes me. I have thousands of experiences quantified into at least ten thousand experience points on Stack Overflow.

> Experience using Stack Exchange sites (huge rep is not required, but we want someone who gets and loves the system.)

This is essentially the same question. My written skills are certainly better than whomever wrote this list. I could volunteer to help out with future job postings too.

> Comfort owning and overseeing a multi-step plan. International site rollouts involve a fair bit of planning, and each one is different. You'd be responsible (with help from a senior CM) for establishing and overseeing execution of a rollout plan.

I'm almost always comfortable with multi-step plans. I follow them from the first step until the last step. I'll be the plan-follower, StackExchange can be the plan creator.

## What we generally look for in Community Manager candidates

> Very strong written skills - you'll need to articulate complex ideas in clear, compelling ways. In the beginning, you will be the sole guiding voice of the company. The community will help decide what it's going to be, but you'll need to help articulate what they should consider, initial guidelines, etc.

I've already established my superior written skills. No one can quite articulate complex ideas as clear as I can. In undergrad, I took a class on both Debate and Logic. I think I'm well equipped for even the most pernicious Spanish troll.

> Moderation / conflict resolution - despite our best efforts, not everyone on the internet always agrees. Part of the job is helping to recognize how to handle conflicts in ways that may not have a winner, but let both parties get back to doing what they came for - helping increase programming knowledge.

I'm well versed in conflicts on this network. Jeff Atwood in the past has even taken me up on a free phone consultation. El Trollo's won't be running the show on my watch.

> Understanding of community dynamics and what motivates people to donate their time on sites like ours

Again, my EXP and reputation should attest to my comprehensive understanding of what makes this site tick.

> Extremely self-motivated with strong ability to prioritize. We ask CMs to help figure out what to do, not just to do it. And many of us work remotely.

I'd be happy to work remotely, or on site. I'd even be willing to negotiate away my Christmas lunch with Jeff for a condo in Barcelona. A position like this demands some level of regional investment.

Comment: "No one can quite articulate complex ideas as clear as I can." This is nit-picky, but you might want to re-phrase this sentence. Is it really true that *no one* can articulate as clearly as you can?

Comment: Yes. It is true.

Comment: I just realized this is a joke. <facepalm>

Comment: That's rude. I'm not joking.

Comment: Good luck :) However, I highly recommend you revise what you have written. It's nice to show your points of strength, but without exaggeration; modesty is good ;) "_My written skills are certainly better than whomever wrote this list._". For this "_I'll be the plan-follower, StackExchange can be the plan creator._" I'm not sure that SE is looking for someone to _implement_ a plan set by SE not by **you**.

Comment: @Omar StackExchange is very much a vertical company. They only want people who know how to do what they request without thinking about that task critically. In order to get the job, I'll have to play that card right. I think I did here.

Comment: +1 Well done. I would hire you, but unfortunately that decision is not in my hand.

Comment: That's weak. There are plenty of better trolls on this page.

Comment: +1 ...well no actually that'd just be trolling. But for comedic value well done Evan :)

Comment: There's only one little big problem: It's illegal to employ children in the US.

Comment: "whomever" lol.