# Is it proper to clarify our answers in a language other than English?

Tags: discussion, comments, languages

Some people whose mother language is not English, have trouble describing their problem or understanding the answers in English. When we are familiar with their first language, is it proper to clarify our answers in that language while we have answered the question in English?

Comment: Of course not. SO is english only. You're not primarily writing for OP, but for all other people who potentially have the same problem who reach the question via google.

Comment: What is wrong with this question? It is just a question, I do not understand why they gave it dowwnvotes

Comment: @Ormoz: voting on Meta is a little different; people are voting on the proposition: *Is it proper to clarify our answers in a language other than english*.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271998/fluent-in-spanish-were-hiring-a-community-manager-for-a-spanish-stack-overflow?cb=1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, Stack Overflow is English *only*.

Your answer is not intended for people speaking your own native language. For it to have lasting value, it needs to be written in the same language as all other posts on the site. That way anyone reaching the question (via Google or via other means) can read both the question and the answers in *one* language. For Stack Overflow that one language is English.

Don't worry too much about spelling and grammar mistakes, we can always help you by editing the post. But if you have trouble expressing yourself in English, then perhaps you need to work on your language skills some more before answering.

In *comments* you can sometimes use a different language, but only to directly communicate with someone who wouldn't otherwise understand English. I've in the past used Dutch in a comment to directly address someone who's grasp of English was less than serviceable.

Comment: "One language rules them all"

Answer (score 7):

You start off assuming that "we have answered the question in English".  That's really the most important thing, because it makes your answer useful to future readers, and lets experts understand it so they can vote.

If you feel that either you or the question asker is more proficient in a language other than English, you can use that also, provided you do it the right way.  Editing an entire translation of the answer into your stackoverflow post is definitely not the right way.  But having a link in your answer to (`more explanation, in <other language>`) hosted either off-site or on one of the foreign-language SO sister sites is perfectly fine.  Rumor has it that the SE.pt folks are getting good value from linking between duplicates in different languages.

A link is never a substitute for an answer on StackOverflow, and an answer in a foreign language is not a substitute for an answer in English, but links and translations can definitely add to the value of an answer.