# Russian speaking community

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

There is huge Russian speaking IT community in Russia, CIS countries and different countries expats. Do you have idea to make Russian Language Stack Overflow (I saw the news about Spanish Language Stack Overflow)?

Comment: Local SOs are well underway. Just register and wait in the Area 51 site about the russian SO.

Answer (score 11):

Sign up for the [Area 51 proposal: Stack Overflow (in Russian)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian) (which does have sufficient support).

Also note in [Fluent in Spanish? We're hiring a Community Manager for a Spanish Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271998/):

> In the interest of full transparency, here are the only languages we're committed to:
>
> Portuguese (live)
> Japanese (in progress)
> Spanish
> Russian

Note the commitment to Russian, though they are still trying to find the appropriate community managers for the different languages.

Comment: I c. Thanks. Well, I'm ready to assist with that if you need.

Comment: Assist me?  Nope.  I'm not an SE employee... I just know where to look for the information.  You might want to read about the community manager for the Spanish one to see how that proposal is moving forward along with what StackExchange is looking for.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-stackoverflow